# how do i install axios latest version using npm?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, api, axios

I need to install axios latest version in my project. Currently axios version in package.json mentioned `"axios": "^0.19.2",`. 
How do i upgrade to latest version?

Comment: I think you can run `npm i axios@latest`

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `npm` command it will automatically update it.

`npm install axios`

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i axios
```

Should install the latest version by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can try or you can try with specific version as well (**npm i axios@0.20.0-0**)

```
npm i axios
```

And also you can always check for version at [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios/v/0.26.1)

Answer (score -1):

Replace version code inside package.json like `"axios": "^0.26.1"` and run  `npm install`